# line integral, stuck in the integral step...

Tags: calculus, integration

Problem: A uniform wire has the shape of that portion of the curve of intersection of the two surfaces
$x^2+y^2=z^2$ and $y^2=x$ connecting the points $(0,0,0)$ and $(1,1,\sqrt{2})$. Find the z-coordinate
of its centroid.

My try:
We need to find $M= \int^{}_{C} \phi(x,y,z)ds$ where $\phi(x,y,z)= a$ and $ds=||\alpha'(t)||dt $ 
$C:\{x^2+y^2 = z^2\} \cap \{ y^2=x\}$ to parameterize the curve we use polar coordinates. If $x=r\sin(t)$ and $y=r\cos(t)$. We have  $$(r\cos(t))^2=r\sin(t) \Rightarrow r(t)=\frac{\sin(t)}{\cos^2(t)}$$ then $$x=\frac{\sin^2(t)}{\cos^2(t)}= \tan^2(t)$$ $$y=\frac{\sin(t)}{\cos^2(t)}\cos(t)=\frac{\sin(t)}{\cos(t)}= \tan(t) $$
and $z=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}=\sqrt{\tan^4(t)+\tan^2(t)}=|\tan(t)|\sqrt{\tan^2(t)+1}=|\tan(t)|\sqrt{\frac{1}{\cos^2(t)}}$

then $\alpha(t)=(\tan^2(t),\tan(t),\frac{\tan(t)}{\cos(t)})$ with $t\in [0,\frac{\pi}{4}]$ then $\alpha'(t)=(2\frac{\tan(t)}{\cos^2(t)},\frac{1}{\cos^2(t)},\frac{1+\sin^2(t)}{\cos^3(t)})$

then again $||\alpha'(t)||=\sqrt{4\frac{\tan^2(t)}{\cos^4(t)}+\frac{1}{\cos^4(t)}+\frac{(1+\sin^2(t))^2}{\cos^6(t)}}$ , so
$$M=\int^{\frac{\pi}{4}}_{0}||\alpha'(t)||dt=\int^{\frac{\pi}{4}}_{0}\sqrt{4\frac{\tan^2(t)}{\cos^4(t)}+\frac{1}{\cos^4(t)}+\frac{(1+\sin^2(t))^2}{\cos^6(t)}}dt $$

then some hint to solve this in a easy way... THANKS

Comment: usually the polar coordinates are $x=r\cos(t)$ and $y=r\sin(t)$

Comment: so did I do it wrong?... and thanks for answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use x for parametrization. with this, 
$$y=\sqrt x$$
$$z=\sqrt {y^2+x^2} =\sqrt {x+x^2}$$

the curve is thus $$(x, \sqrt x, \sqrt {x+x^2})$$

$$ds = \sqrt {1 + \frac1{4x}+\frac{(1+2x)^2}{4(x+x^2)}} dx$$

I guess the rest is not very crazy...I will check that out tomorrow.

Comment: I had done this way but could not solve the integral , then thought that using polar coordinates it'll be easier, but I'm in the same. And thanks for answer